# Curl multiple url using batch and save the result in txt file

Tags: batch-file, curl

I want to get data from several websites using curl with a batch file, then save the curl results into a text file.

the syntax that I know is this:

```
curl "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587492&lon=125.952764" >> output.txt
curl "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587493&lon=125.952765" >> output.txt
curl "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587494&lon=125.952766" >> output.txt
curl "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587495&lon=125.952767" >> output.txt
curl "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587496&lon=125.952768" >> output.txt
```

I changed the curl above into looping and it works fine. I have set LF so that the next result can move to the next line, but it didn't work.
Here my script :

```
@echo off
set setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set url1="https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587492&lon=125.952764"
set url2="https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587493&lon=125.952765"
set url3="https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587494&lon=125.952766"
set url4="https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587495&lon=125.952767"
set url5="https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587496&lon=125.952768"

(set LF=^
%=EMPTY=%
)

echo %url1%
for %%x in (set) do (
 curl %url1%%LF%
 curl %url2%%LF%
 curl %url3%%LF%
 curl %url4%%LF%
 curl %url5%%LF%
)> output.txt
```

Comment: I want the curl to be made like this https://gist.github.com/shrop/5da5d831f571d19f0be6e9183b1ebf55

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information. You should note from your new found knowledge that you should not be using `for /L` at all in the scenario you've posted. Also none of the `%LF%` variables are required. How about you explain exactly what the task is, because there is no good reason to set all of those URL's into variables like that, and then reference each of them in a loop to do exactly what your original five lines were doing!

Comment: Seems you are guessing syntax; type `for /?` and read the help; you'll find out that you don't need `/L`; also "it doesn't work well" is not a failure description; plrease read [mcve]…

Comment: I have changed my script again and it works. But they combine the outputs into one, I want the next output to move to the next line.
By the way, thanks for the advice and input beforehand.

Comment: I've added "LF" to break the result into new line, but it didn't work.

Comment: you added the `LF` as a part of the parameter to `curl`. You want to `echo %LF%` instead: `curl %url1% & echo %LF%` etc.

Comment: your `for %%x in (set) do ...` loop doesn't make sense. See `for /?` for proper usage.

Comment: How many locations do you plan to use? Are they all consecutive coordinates like in your example ("going diagonal through the landscape")?

Comment: to echo a linefeed, you don't need `%LF%`. Just `echo(` is enough.

Comment: i've added curl %url1% & echo %LF%. The output results can move to the next line. But the output says "echo is off" at end of line.

... ["- 23.509751", "- 19.5", "120.064128", "126.001296"]} ECHO is off.
... ["- 5.4138916", "- 1.3024076", "113.9911308", "117.900953"]} ECHO is off.

Comment: Because your `%LF%` doesn't work as intended. Forget about `%LF%` and use just `echo(`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it really strange you want to have an ordinary text-file as output while the urls you're processing are actually JSON objects. To properly save multiple JSON objects as valid JSON you have to put them in a JSON array.
I'd say you're much better off with a tool like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) to work this out.

You could manually enter the 5 urls you mentioned:

```json
xidel -se ^"^
  array{^
    json-doc('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2^&lat=-19.587492^&lon=125.952764'),^
    json-doc('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2^&lat=-19.587493^&lon=125.952765'),^
    json-doc('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2^&lat=-19.587494^&lon=125.952766'),^
    json-doc('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2^&lat=-19.587495^&lon=125.952767'),^
    json-doc('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2^&lat=-19.587496^&lon=125.952768')^
  }^
"
```

...but you can also build them dynamically:

```json
xidel -se ^"^
  let $json:={'format':'jsonv2','lat':-19.587492,'lon':125.952764} return^
  map:merge(^
    ($json,{'lat':$json/lat - 0.000001},{'lon':$json/lon + 0.000001}),^
    {'duplicates':'use-last'}^
  )^
" --printed-json-format=compact
{"format": "jsonv2", "lat": -19.587493, "lon": 125.952765}
```

```json
xidel -s --xquery ^"^
  let $json:={'format':'jsonv2','lat':-19.587492,'lon':125.952764}^
  for $x in 0 to 4^
  return^
  map:merge(^
    (^
      $json,^
      {'lat':$json/lat - ($x * 0.000001)},^
      {'lon':$json/lon + ($x * 0.000001)}^
    ),^
    {'duplicates':'use-last'}^
  )^
" --printed-json-format=compact
{"format": "jsonv2", "lat": -19.587492, "lon": 125.952764}
{"format": "jsonv2", "lat": -19.587493, "lon": 125.952765}
{"format": "jsonv2", "lat": -19.587494, "lon": 125.952766}
{"format": "jsonv2", "lat": -19.587495, "lon": 125.952767}
{"format": "jsonv2", "lat": -19.587496, "lon": 125.952768}
```

```json
xidel -s --xquery ^"^
  let $json:={'format':'jsonv2','lat':-19.587492,'lon':125.952764}^
  for $x in 0 to 4^
  return^
  request-combine(^
    'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse',^
    map:merge(^
      (^
        $json,^
        {'lat':$json/lat - ($x * 0.000001)},^
        {'lon':$json/lon + ($x * 0.000001)}^
      ),^
      {'duplicates':'use-last'}^
    )^
  )/url^
"
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587492&lon=125.952764
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587493&lon=125.952765
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587494&lon=125.952766
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587495&lon=125.952767
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-19.587496&lon=125.952768
```

```json
xidel -s --xquery ^"^
  array{^
    let $json:={'format':'jsonv2','lat':-19.587492,'lon':125.952764}^
    for $x in 0 to 4^
    return^
    request-combine(^
      'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse',^
      map:merge(^
        (^
          $json,^
          {'lat':$json/lat - ($x * 0.000001)},^
          {'lon':$json/lon + ($x * 0.000001)}^
        ),^
        {'duplicates':'use-last'}^
      )^
    )/json-doc(url)^
  }^
"
[
  {
    "place_id": 259803148,
    "licence": "Data c OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "relation",
    "osm_id": 11690317,
    "lat": "-21.5177325",
    "lon": "123.52595630504817",
    "place_rank": 20,
    "category": "boundary",
    "type": "administrative",
    "importance": 0.25,
    "addresstype": "suburb",
    "name": "Telfer",
    "display_name": "Telfer, Shire Of East Pilbara, Western Australia, Australia",
    "address": {
      "suburb": "Telfer",
      "municipality": "Shire Of East Pilbara",
      "state": "Western Australia",
      "country": "Australia",
      "country_code": "au"
    },
    "boundingbox": ["-23.509751", "-19.5", "120.064128", "126.001296"]
  },
  [...]
]
```

Or of course the minified version (without the need of escape-characters):

```json
xidel -s --xquery "array{let $json:={'format':'jsonv2','lat':-19.587492,'lon':125.952764} for $x in 0 to 4 return request-combine('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse',map:merge(($json,{'lat':$json/lat - ($x * 0.000001)},{'lon':$json/lon + ($x * 0.000001)}),{'duplicates':'use-last'}))/json-doc(url)}"
```